# Hello, I'm new at mysql. please help me to solve mysql error logs

Tags: mysql

I get occasional error establishing database connection error on wp site. It happens regularly. To prevent it from happening again, I need to fix it, after the error I checked MySQL error logs and they are something like this

```
[ERROR] mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
[ERROR] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
[ERROR] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
[ERROR] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
[ERROR] Data Dictionary initialization failed
[ERROR] Aborting
```

How do I know what causes it and how can I fix it?